# Load different type of custom cell (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, cell

Hi Guys I have a problem!
I want to change the custom cell if mediaurl==@"string" and move the label on the left if i not load the picture... How can I do? Any issue? if I create a label from code the the method call if mediaurl==@"string" I will make a mistake.

Comment: Hello ! could you remove the code that isn't needed to your question ? About your question, you just need to adjust the frame depending if you have image or not. So a if/else condition.

Comment: yes but the cell is very dirty because there is also the content of the precedent image label and so on because they are Reausable!

Comment: there is a command to erase the content of a cell before that i put in the new content? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be related to your other question
[iPhone Problem with custom cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877658/iphone-problem-with-custom-cell)

What you want to do is use two different cell types, correct? If so, you should define two different cell identifiers (eg: @"NormalCell" & @"CustomCell") and dequeue only the kind of cell you need for displaying the current item.

Instead of modifying the cell to suit the data, choose what kind of cell to use depending on what you need to display.

To do this, you need to move your check for string equality (or whatever you use to determine cell type) to before you dequeue a reusable cell.